# How to open V3 onion links using Onion Browser Button for Chrome?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, browsers, add-on, tor-button

I am using Onion Browser Button addons for Chrome on Windows 10. And I can't to access V3 .onion links.

I had been asked lot of times to developer to build a new version, but no answer.

Anyone knows how to open V3 .onion links using addons for Chrome on Windows, please?

(I can't to install Tor Browser on notebook - not administrator user)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever this Onion Browser Button thing is, this is not from the Tor Project and is possibly malware, stealing your data, etc. so I would suggest removing it ASAP.

If you want to run Tor in Chrome on Windows 10, you need to start [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/download/) and then start Chrome. You will need to then add a socks 5 proxy to Chrome. Google doesn't make that easy. The socks proxy will be 127.0.0.1 port 9150. If you close Tor Browser, the proxy will stop. By this way none of this is a suggested way of doing things.

The [point of Tor](https://2019.www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en) is anonymity online. By using a browser that is different from what everyone else uses and is untested, you will be greatly reducing the chances that you will be anonymous.

Comment: I can install Tor Browser, but I can't to open because of McAfee antivirus is blocking Tor.exe. And I can't to change the policy to put Tor.exe in the Whitelist, because I'm not administrator.

Comment: To use Tor-Buttom, I have renamed file "Tor.exe" to "Tor.ex". And I have updated run.js to considering "tor.ex". And then it works. 

Can I rename file "Tor;.exe" to "tor.ex" on Tor Browser to be Ok for McAfee antivirus?